# Tranferring the html input for the Qt

Tags: html, c++, qt, qwebview

I have a `QWebView` and inside of it, say there's some comboboxes, radiobuttons or some form.

Showing that website in the `QWebView`, is there any way to get those information that are checkeds/filled or whatever (The html webpage is mine)?

I'm using Qt for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to these elements with `QWebElement` objects :

```
QWebView myWebView;
QWebPage * webPage = myWebView.page();
QWebFrame * frame = webPage->mainFrame();
QWebElement myElement = frame->documentElement();
```

`myElement` can be manipulated just like you can do in JavaScript with the DOM API. For more information about using a QWebElement, you can refer to the QWebElement official documentation : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html

Comment: Seriously, that probably hided from me when I was reading the documentation. Thanks for help.